# Migrate Bugzilla Issues to github Issue Tracker

Tags: git, github, dvcs, bugzilla, issue-tracking

I would like to migrate all my [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) issues to an Issue Tracker at github.com ([Example](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues)) (you get an issue tracker per repository).

1) **Are there tools out there?**

2) **How did you do it?**

Thanks for any advices, I will write a summary at the end how I finally did it (hopefully not manually!)

Comment: I know I've seen "Google Code -> Github" converters. So if you find one for converting "Bugzilla -> Google Code" then you could do it in two steps. Quite a roundabout way but it's possible that's the easiest solution out there.

Comment: any pointer to the Google Code -> Github converter?

Comment: I don't remember where I saw it. Maybe somewhere on reddit. A quick Google search turns up https://github.com/arthur-debert/google-code-issues-migrator but I haven't tried it...

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and comment here my results...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to export your issues from Bugzilla, and then use the GitHub API to upload the issues into GitHub:

http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

*(note that the old issue-import through GitHub support channels is discontinued)*

This does mean your issue numbers will change, so you might want to append a 'Bugzilla-Id' footer to your issue description, so you can use GitHub's free-text search on issues to find them from the old Bugzilla ids.

As far as exporting your data from Bugzilla goes, I think your options are:

- Bugzilla's HTML export
- Bugzilla [JSON-RPC](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.0/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/JSONRPC.html)
- Connecting directly to the [bugzilla database](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/p4dti/tool/cgi/bugzilla-schema/index.cgi?action=single&version=3.4.2&view=View%20schema)

Good luck! If you do write an export script, I'd encourage you to open-source it on GitHub!

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered the same problem trying to migrate Bugzilla issues of a W3C project to GitHub, so I ended up

- Writing a [RESTful API wrapper](https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/restzilla), that scrapes the Bugzilla (the W3C bugzilla has the API disabled)
- Writing a [hackish CoffeeScript program/script](https://gist.github.com/4375613) to use that wrapper and create the issues on GitHub.

I hope that my script can be easily modified to fit the purposes of you, too.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Perl script to handle this last year; effectively you save the bugs you want as XML via Bugzilla's built-in UI for it, and the script uploads them as individual issues.

It uses `Net::GitHub::V2` for the uploading API and GitHub's oauth system for authentication.  It reads the user and repo config from the environment by default because I was running it from other scripts; but all the variables are at the top of the script if you want to customise.

https://github.com/rowanj/BugzillaMigrate

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the help of Bondable
https://web.archive.org/web/20160304172242/http://www.bondable.com/integrations/p/services/bugzilla

You can actually create a lot of integrations with Bugzilla

*Note: As of 2020-03-11, www.bondable.com is no longer hosting a web app, and the original link is spammy*